# How to set focus on element on moving the mouse over it in Selenium WebDriver using Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, focus

I am a beginner in Selenium WebDriver and I'm using this test on the StackOverflow homepage. These will be the steps of my test:

1. Firstly, go to the homepage of the StackOverflow.
2. Then, move the mouse on the **Users** button such that it will be focused. (We don't have to click on it just hover the mouse over it.)
3. Now, find the active element on the screen (i.e. the element which is
   currently focused) and then click on it.

I want the Users button to be clicked because it is focussed currently but that's not happening. Instead the **Questions** button is clicked on.
Here is my code for the same test.

```
package insertCartridge;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class Practice {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\SELENIUM\\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;
    String baseUrl = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
    WebElement Users = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/header/div/div[1]/nav/ol/li[5]"));
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.moveToElement(Users).perform();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.switchTo().activeElement().click();
 }
}
```

I am not able to understand why I am not getting the expected output. Please help.

Comment: you don't want to click on users?

Comment: @PotnuruRavi, yes, I don't want to click on USERS. Just move the mouse cursor on it so that it can be focused and then find the active element (which should be USERS) and then click on it.

Comment: locate the element(using coordinates) and using actions you can move to the Users tab. Actions builder = new Actions(driver); 
builder.MoveToElement(WaitForElement(By.CssSelector(starElement)), location.X, location.Y);

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner and I'm having problems understanding your code and I've few doubts.
What is the starElement here?
Is WaitforElement a function or you mean ExplicitWait by this thing?

Comment: starElement is locator value of users and WaitForElement is a class.

Comment: @PotnuruRavi, do we have to find the location using this : Point point = table.getLocation(); 
  int xcoord = point.getX();
  int ycoord = point.getY();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why `Actions` class is not focusing the element. Its an issue or something as so many time i have trouble with Actions class in Firefox browser.

Still you have one alternative way to Focus on desired element and then perform click on focused element i.e. `JavascriptExecutor`

Here you is your code :

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('nav-users').focus();");

System.out.println(driver.switchTo().activeElement().getTagName());       
driver.switchTo().activeElement().click();
```

Comment: Is there any method to get the Element by Xpath? Since I am using this method on my web application in which the getElementById method is not working. Although the method suggested by you works well on the StackOverflow.

Comment: @DG4, Yes there is a way to use xpath. you have to use `evaluate()` of javascript. try this and replace xpath in it `jse.executeScript("document.evaluate(\"//a[@id='nav-users']\",document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.focus();");`

Comment: I followed your suggestion but it is showing error in the above code using xpath. This was the error: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ ). Sorry if it sounds dumb. I don't have any prior experience with Javascript.

Comment: Have you used the same line as i have posted or did some changes ?

Comment: Yes, I have used the same line as yours exactly.

Comment: Strange, I  have used the same and its perfect at my end

Comment: That's what I have written in Eclipse:
 JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
     jse.executeScript("document.evaluate(\"//a[@id='nav-users']\‌​",document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.focus();");
     System.out.println(driver.switchTo().activeElement().getTagName());

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152135/discussion-between-tuks-and-dg4).

Comment: I'm trying this ...
document.evaluate("//input[@name='endDate']", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.focus()
... but it's returning undefined